# Flutter: Sliding Up Panel embeded in each Item of Horizontal viewpager

Tags: flutter

In android native we can use viewpager with BottomSheet as an Implementation.In flutter is it possible to have a horizontal viewpager (each item in viewpager have buttons and text)and for each item viewpager we install Sliding Up Panel? Any comment will be a big help.

Comment: Yes try pageview and bottom sheet

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!! We have a viewpager like this youtube.com/watch?v=G_kU8fAdYc8&t=205s. and want each item can be a modal_bottom_sheet. is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is what I believe you're looking for! It has a variety of bottom slidable sheets:

https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet

*cheers*

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!!  We have a viewpager like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_kU8fAdYc8&t=205s. and want each item can be a modal_bottom_sheet. is that possible?

Comment: @YANSONGGUO Yup, absolutely doable. Probably just fix the height of the bottom sheet to 1/2 the height of the screen, and then wrap your content in a `SingleChildScrollView` with the `axis` property set to `Axis.horizontal`. Then you can put all those cards in the bottom sheet and they'll play nice. If the answer was helpful, remember to upvote it for the next person :)

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for the ambiguity. We need the viewpager items to be floating on our background. So the modal_bottom_sheet must be in the view pager. Is it even possible ?

Comment: It’s possible to have the bottom sheet contain multiple “screens” (tabs or viewpager’s if I understand you correctly).

Comment: Exactly the opposite :). multiple “screens” and each contain expandable bottom sheet (so we essentially show a thumbnail use “screens” and when user wanna to see the detail they can expand the "screen" )

Comment: @YANSONGGUO, sorry, didn't get that right away, but yes, bottom sheets can definitely do that!